# php artisan tinker problem on laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

Thinker is not working on laravel homestead (laravel 6.9, php 7.4). When I try to use `php artisan tinker` I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'XdgBaseDir\Xdg' not found
```

Comment: I would suggest running `composer install` to make sure you have all of your dependencies

Comment: sure but this is an error after that

Comment: Hmm, i very much doubt it is an issue with either Laravel 6 or PHP 7.4 as it is Symfony that is complaining. This can usually be a result of missing dependencies or caching. Try `composer dump-autoload` to refresh your class list.

Comment: already do that 

Comment: There isn't much more I can suggest right now without knowing more about the project itself. This could be an issue with a composer package you have installed or a misconfiguration in an config/environment file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of your code is requiring the Xdg library, so can you try adding it

```
composer require dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir
```